# Young garbage collection longer pause with java 7 vs java 6

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-7, java-6

I noticed that each young garbage collection with java 7 takes on average 10 more milliseconds than with java 6. I'm using `1.6.0_31` and `1.7.0_21`. The configuration hasn't changed, neither has the hardware, JVM arguments are:

```
-server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:+AggressiveOpts -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:NewSize=256m
```

- Java 7:

```
 S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       PC     PU    YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
26176.0 26176.0 3531.6  0.0   209792.0 21648.8   786432.0   86777.6   49472.0 49350.1     82    1.830   0      0.000    1.
```

- Java 6

```
 S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       PC     PU    YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
26176.0 26176.0  0.0   1210.5 209792.0 95873.4   786432.0   65327.1   35968.0 35891.2     83    0.620   0      0.000    0.620
```

I also looked at each individual times, and with java 6, each `YGC` takes ~10ms vs java 7 is 20ms. Did something change between version 6 and 7 that could explain this behavior?

**EDIT:** I noticed that java 7 runs in 64 bits mode, whereas java 6 use a 32 bits JVM, could that explain the difference?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect the size of the eden and young generation is different by default and this can change this sort of behaviour. Can you print the actual sizes?

Comment: Different algorithm or different parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Default `-XX:NewRatio` for Java 6 is `8` but for the Java 7 it is `2`. so in java 6 the size of young generation is less than java 7 hence the difference i feel.

Because time collecting the garbage from a city is directly proportional to how large the city is. if city size increases hence the time.

Comment: I'm setting the size of the new generation via -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:NewSize=256m, so I expect it to be same for both version